# How to Select All checkboxes with one button with ONLY HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css, checkbox

Has anyone seen an example of selecting all the checkboxes without any javascript or jquery? If so, if anyone can show me an example or a site where this has been seen?

Thank you in advance

Comment: You can't have buttons perform actions without javascript

Comment: Is there a reason for your ONLY HTML and CSS requirements?

Comment: No, there isn't

Comment: are you using the checkboxes as a filter?  If so, you could just have one checkbox value as `select all`.

Comment: This is a valid question. I do not get why people downvote it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although this is something you should probably be using JavaScript for (few people will have it disabled, and it's very simple to add a message with `<noscript>` telling people to turn it on), contrary to what others are saying, I believe it is possible with a bit of CSS magic.

Here I have two sets of checkboxes that appear identical to the end user. When the "check both boxes" checkbox is checked, the ones which are pre-checked are displayed. Otherwise, the first set is displayed. On the server end, check the status of the "check both boxes" checkbox to see which set should be ignored.

```css
#bothChecked {
  display: none;
}

#bothBox:checked ~ #bothChecked{
  display: block;
}

#bothBox:checked ~ #bothUnchecked{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="checkbox" id="bothBox"> Check both boxes<br>
  <div id="bothUnchecked">
    <input type="checkbox"> Checkbox 1<br>
    <input type="checkbox"> Checkbox 2
  </div>
  <div id="bothChecked">
    <input type="checkbox" checked disabled> Checkbox 1<br>
    <input type="checkbox" checked disabled> Checkbox 2
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, unfortunately due to security reasons I am unable to use JS (I hate that I can't). I have had to do a lot of research so I can make what normally works on js, work only with HTML and CSS. This was super helpful and it help fix a problem. I very much appreciate it!

Comment: @iz_anne JavaScript in itself isn't a security issue - it's only if someone figures a way of injecting a script into your page that it becomes an issue. Anyway, I don't know the exact context for your requirements and it's none of my business. Glad to know this solution works for you. I don't know what impact this may have on assistive technologies such as screen readers, so watch out for that if it matters under your circumstances.

Comment: The problem I find with this solution is that it only works if all checkboxes are in the same container. It wont work with checkboxes inside a data table for example, where items are separated by <tr> and <td>

Answer (score -1):

@spacer-gif was faster while I was making a Codepen for you. I can only repeat what he said. This is sooooo hacky that it hurts :D
But it was fun to make.

https://codepen.io/nemanjaglumac/pen/BVKNoM

```
<div class="container">
  <input type="checkbox" id=trigger>
  <label for="trigger">
    <button class="button">Button</button>
  </label>

  <div class="checked">
    <input type="checkbox" id="firstChecked" checked>
    <label for="firstChecked">First</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="secondChecked" checked>
    <label for="secondChecked">Second</label>
  </div>
  <div class="unchecked">
    <input type="checkbox" id="firstChecked">
    <label for="firstChecked">First</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="secondChecked">
    <label for="secondChecked">Second</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Once again, if you want full control, use JS.